# Vite project starts with an error "Preprocessor dependency "sass" failed to load"

Tags: node.js, sass, vite

I install my dependencies in my Vite project (React+TS) and try to run it (I use yarn dev), and then I get an error:

> Preprocessor dependency "sass" failed to load

This is my package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-use-websocket": "3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
```

This problem occurs on my work computer (I did the project on my personal laptop and everything runs fine there, the project was cloned from my repository).

Full error message:

> [plugin:vite:css] Preprocessor dependency "sass" failed to load:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pop')

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Node v21.0.0 did not include a `navigator.userAgent` value, breaking compatibility with Dart when compiled with JS.

Downgrade to v20.8.1 or upgrade to v21.1.0 to fix the issue.

GitHub issue and resolution thread: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53784

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Node v21.1.0 fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me as well. The problem at least in v21.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

In case downgrading node is not an option for you, I worked around this problem by applying the following patch to `sass.dart.js` (in `node_modules/sass`):

```
diff -U2 sass.dart.js.orig sass.dart.js
--- sass.dart.js.orig   2023-11-11 18:33:51.444169600 +0100
+++ sass.dart.js        2023-11-11 18:36:34.287463700 +0100
@@ -116830,4 +116830,5 @@
     if (typeof navigator != "object") return hooks;
     var ua = navigator.userAgent;
+    if (!ua) return hooks;
     if (ua.indexOf("DumpRenderTree") >= 0) return hooks;
     if (ua.indexOf("Chrome") >= 0) {
@@ -116864,4 +116865,5 @@
     B.C_JS_CONST5 = function(hooks) {
   var userAgent = typeof navigator == "object" ? navigator.userAgent : "";
+  if (!userAgent) return hooks;
   if (userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") == -1) return hooks;
   var getTag = hooks.getTag;
@@ -116881,4 +116883,5 @@
     B.C_JS_CONST4 = function(hooks) {
   var userAgent = typeof navigator == "object" ? navigator.userAgent : "";
+  if (!userAgent) return hooks;
   if (userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") == -1) return hooks;
   var getTag = hooks.getTag;
```

I arrived at this patch by inspecting each error location and every time finding that the user agent is not defined and guessing what behavioral looked most plausible based on the surrounding code. So this is by no means proper software engineering or sustainable in any way. You still don't need to downgrade node though ;-).